# Music player controls still a pain in WP8.1

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, music, xbox-music

It was a big complaint in WP7 that the music controls would get stuck on the lock screen. In WP8 they fade away after a few seconds but they're still there... I listen to some music for a few minutes and now 24 hours later I still have to see the music controls every time I unlock the phone or adjust the volume. I can't see the music player app open so how am I supposed to make the darn thing go away? Not only is it irritating, I worry I might clumsily press play when unlocking my phone and blare out something - typically when trying to put my phone on silent would be just typical!

Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to get rid of the player controls is using an app like "Stop the music" (I'm not the developer and there are several other ones doing the same).

http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=a99cd038-1d63-49a1-b989-22d3482b8f96

You should also consider voting for this "feature" on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Comment: Is there already a feature request you're aware of and can link to?

Comment: @Mr.Boy You can vote for this request. https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2524771-hide-last-played-music-and-controls-from-volume-co

Comment: "Quite a few" apps stop the music (Instagram seems to, at least for me). The media playing app seems to get kicked out a lot more easily on WP8.x compared to 7.x (I *preferred the 7.x behaviour)